# how can i disabled sound error when a one line in error in vsCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I recently had a problem coding in VSCode
When a line encounters an error, VSCode favors me and makes a sound
In the sense that this line has encountered an error
I want to disable this sound
Also, I did not install any special extensions
Thank you for your help
version : 1.65.2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the settings section
Search for "**audiocues**"
In the "**Line Hase Error**" section
Select the "**Off**" option
In this way, the beep will not sound in any line that we encounter an error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Starting in VS Code 1.87, use the `signals.lineHasError` setting and set the child property for `audioCue` to off. Prior to that, use the `audioCues.lineHasError` setting.